# Non-String Configuration in ASP.Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-core, configuration

Currently, I am using strings to define and consume routes, roles, policies, etc. It is easy to misspell or get the string values wrong, as they are not part of the IDE auto-completion and type checking.

Is there a way to utilize some kind of references or symbols in ASP.NET Core 3.1? Maybe through configuration providers and DI?

What I would like to see is to define these string configuration values once somewhere, and then reference them in various parts of the application?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use constants classes?

```
public static class RoutingConstants
{
  public const string Route1 = "route1";
  ...
}
```

And the same thing for any other need

You could then access the constant everywhere like this `RoutingConstants.Route1`

Comment: That is a possible solution. I am curious if there are also other specialized solutions for configuration, maybe with configuration providers and DI?

Answer (score 0):

**Authorize with roles**:
You can refactor the roles into constants and consume them like this:

```
public class StaticRoles
{
    public const string A = "A";
    public const string B = "B";
    public const string C = "C";
    public const string ABC = "A, B, C";
}
```

Use these constants like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = StaticRoles.ABC)]
[Route("foo")]
public IActionResult Foo()
```

**Consuming routes in views**:
When generating links, you can use tag helpers for links which automatically read the Route attribute from the controller method:

```
<a asp-controller="@nameof(HomeController).Replace("Controller", string.Empty)" asp-action="@nameof(HomeController.Foo)">Foo</a>
```

You should refactor `.Replace("Controller", string.Empty)` into a String extension method to reduce code bloat.

**Consuming routes in code**:
If you want to have the same functionality as the tag helpers in code, you can use the [LinkGenerator class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which is automatically injected

Use dependency injection to get the reference to the `LinkGenerator`

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly LinkGenerator linkGenerator;

    public HomeController(LinkGenerator linkGenerator)
    {
        this.linkGenerator = linkGenerator;
    }

    // ..
}
```

Inside `HomeController`, you can then use

```
linkGenerator.GetPathByAction(
    nameof(HomeController.Index),
    nameof(HomeController).Replace("Controller", string.Empty))
};
```

`GetPathByAction` has a third parameter when the route has parameters as part of the URL:

```
linkGenerator.GetPathByAction(
    nameof(HomeController.Index),
    nameof(HomeController).Replace("Controller", string.Empty),
    values: new { version = user.Version})
};
```

Comment: @geeko: Was my answer useful for you?